# What is the correct title for a "Book of abstracts"

Tags: word-form

Of the following three titles for a collection of conference proceedings, which is in the correct form?

1. Book of abstracts
2. Abstract book
3. Abstracts book

I believe that the first form should be preferable, but the three versions seem to be equally common at least in scientific literature. Thanks!

Comment: They're not equally common. "Abstracts book" is much rarer than the other two, and I suspect it is used mainly by non-native English speakers. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Book+of+Abstracts%2CAbstract+Book%2CAbstracts+Book&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBook%20of%20Abstracts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAbstract%20Book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAbstracts%20Book%3B%2Cc0). Most of the time, nouns used as adjectives aren't pluralized. We say *"flower shop"*, even though most customers buy more than one flower at at a time.

Comment: Another reason not to use *abstracts book*: it's *songbook,  prayer book, address book, word book, price book*, and not *songsbook, prayers book, addresses book, words book, prices book*, and even though these books contain more than one song, prayer, address,  etc.

Comment: I think "Book of Abstracts" sounds natural.

Comment: Either of the first two seems fine to me. The third one does not sound right at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Book of Abstracts" works the best. With appropriate context, "abstract book" would be fine and has the best "sound" to my ears but out of context someone might interpret it to be a book that is abstract. The last one would be understood I think, but as the comments mention, it's not a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I've usually seen such things called simply "proceedings of [conference/institution]."

Comment: In my field, a *proceedings* is not a *book of abstracts* (or at least, not before the internet). A *proceedings* was a document of record which was disseminated after the conference. A *book of abstracts* was a collection of abstracts of the talks, so you could decide which one to go to; it wasn't meant to be anything permanent. (Of course, now books of abstracts are recorded on the web, and some proceedings are no longer hard-copy but web-only, so in some sense they're converging.)

Comment: I've seen the two used interchangeably in my academic experience. Perhaps there's a greater distinction in the use for your field, @PeterShor.